# Rate of convergence of ${x_n}=\arctan ({x_{n-1}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Find the rate of convergence of : 
${x_n}=\arctan ({x_{n-1}})$. Well, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{{x_{n+1}}}{{x_n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\arctan({x_n})}{\arctan({x_{n-1}})}=l,$$
where $l$ is the point where the series converges to. I can't calculate this limit so I can not find $l$.

The next step would be to calculate: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{{x_{n+1}}-l}{({x_n}-l)^p}$$

Basically this question has to do with the $l$ calculation which will help me define the rate of converge for ${x_n}$. Any hint about the limit would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would be $x_0$ or $x_1$?

Comment: @kingW3 ${x_0}$ would be a constant and we will start from $i=1$ for the sequence ${x_i}$

Comment: am i missing something? only solution of $x = \arctan(x)$ is $x = 0.$ moreover $x - \arctan(x) = \frac13 x^3 + \ldots$ so i would expect the convergence to be cubic.

Comment: @abel yes, you are right, though beyond that I have to find the rate of convergence which requires the calculation of the second limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{arctan({x_{n}})}{(arctan({x_{n-1}}))^p}$

Comment: @adjik, shouldn't the limit be one? $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} = 1.$

Comment: @abel so the rate of convergence, in this case, can be defined by this limit? $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{arctan(x)}{x}$ .

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comments, both the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n^p}$ are easy to compute given the observation that $x_n \to 0$. So let me demonstrate a method of finding an asymptotic expansion of $(x_n)$ instead.

---

A hint is that you can estimate the growth of $x_n^{-2}$ more easily. For instance, assuming that $x_1 > 0$,

**Step 1.** Since $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing and bounded, $(x_n)$ converges. The limit must be a fixed point of $\arctan$, which is exactly $0$.

**Step 2.** Notice that $\frac{1}{\arctan^2 x} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$. From this,

$$ \frac{1}{x_{n+1}^2} - \frac{1}{x_n^2} = \frac{2}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x_n^2). $$

In view of [*Stolz–Cesàro theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n^{-2}}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{2}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x_n^2)}{(n+1) - n} = \frac{2}{3} $$

and hence $x_n^{-2} \sim \frac{2}{3}n$.

**Step 3.** Now using $\frac{1}{\arctan^2 x} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{15}x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$ and the previous step,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n^{-2} - \frac{2}{3}n}{\log n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{15}x_{n+1}^2 + \mathcal{O}(x_n^4)}{\log(n+1) - \log n} = -\frac{1}{10} $$

and hence $x_n^{-2} = \frac{2}{3}n - \frac{1}{10}\log n + o(\log n)$.

**Step 4.** Now write

$$ \frac{1}{x_n^2} - \left( \frac{2}{3}n - \frac{1}{10}\log n \right)
= \frac{1}{x_1^2} - \frac{2}{3} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{x_{k+1}^2} - \frac{1}{x_k^2} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{10}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \right). $$

Using the previous step, it is easy to check that the right-hand side converges as $n\to\infty$ with the error term decaying at most as fast as $\mathcal{O}(\frac{\log n}{n})$. So there exists a constant $C$ such that

$$ x_n^{-2} = \frac{2}{3}n - \frac{1}{10}\log n + C + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right). $$

---

Using this estimation above, we can easily check that

$$ x_n = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}} \left( 1 + \frac{3}{40}\frac{\log n}{n}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right). $$

Comment: Nice answer.Now I see the asymptotes method in use.+1.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me for recursive schemes it is convinient to use the following. If we are already at the limit, then $a= arctan(a)$. It remains to find a. That is $tg(a)= a$, one solution is $a=0$, there is no other solutions as $tg(a)$ grows faster than $a$ for $a \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, and decreases faster for $a \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$.

The rate at some point $x$ is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{arctan(x_{n})}{x_{n}}$. Which is the same as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{arctan(x)}{x}$, which is the same as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{tgx}$, which is one (as $\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{x}{sinx}=1$ and $cos(0)=1$).

Comment: yeah I see, so you are saying that my $l$ should be 0 due to the fact that $arctan(x)$ has only one $l$ such that $arctan(l)=l$. But still, there would be a problem finding the rate of convergence because I won't be able to calculate the second limit.

Comment: This answer did not solve the question, namely the rate .

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I really don't get what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: @kolobokish may you clarify why the rate at some point $x$ is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{arctan(x_{n})}{x_{n}}$. Shouldn't it be $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{arctan({x_{n}})}{(arctan({x_{n-1}}))^p}$?

Comment: It's the same. Why pushing behind when I can write everything trough $x_{n}$, why use to different notations. (And I don't understand why is here $p$). As far as I remember rate of convergence doesn't require anything like that.

Comment: @kolobokish $p$ is the order of the convergence which most of the times is set to 1.